# I would like assistance in fixing my code

Tags: javascript

```
   /* Constants */
var START_RADIUS = 1;
var INCREMENT = 1;
var CHANGE_COLORS_AT = 10;
var circle;

function start(){
    //Circle is being added once in the start function.
    circle = new Circle(START_RADIUS);
    circle.setPosition(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
    add(circle);

    //This is the command that will execute every 50 miliseconds.
    setTimer(grow, 50);
}

function grow(){
    //This will keep the circle from continually growing past the height of the (premade) canvas.
    while(circle.getRadius()*2 != getHeight()){
        START_RADIUS = START_RADIUS + INCREMENT;
        circle.setRadius(START_RADIUS);
        //Changes the color every +10 the radius grows.
        if(circle.getRadius() % CHANGE_COLORS_AT == 0){
            circle.setColor(Randomizer.nextColor());
        }
    }
}
```

This code is meant to make a continually growing circle (until the diameter hits the top of the canvas). This is for school, and is using a very simplified version of javascript from the website 'codehs.com'. I have been working on this code for a while, and would like some insight on how to fix it.

Comment: How is `getHeight` and other getters defined?

Comment: JavaScript != Java

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

Actually fixed it. The problem was, there was one "while" loop, *and* the "setTimer" command, which also more or less acts as a while loop. This made the circle instantly inflate to full size. The fixed code is here!VV

```
/* Constants */
var START_RADIUS = 1;
var INCREMENT = 1;
var CHANGE_COLORS_AT = 10;
var circle;

function start(){
    //Circle is being added once in the start function.
    circle = new Circle(START_RADIUS);
    circle.setPosition(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
    add(circle);

    //This is the command that will execute every 50 miliseconds.
    setTimer(grow, 5);
}

function grow(){
    START_RADIUS = START_RADIUS + INCREMENT;
    circle.setRadius(START_RADIUS);
    if(circle.getRadius() % CHANGE_COLORS_AT == 0){
        circle.setColor(Randomizer.nextColor());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for updating us :)